# x-axis label is cropped when SVG is converted to image D3.js

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, svg, c3.js

I'm using C3.js to generate line chart. Once SVG is created, I'm converting it to .png image using canvas.

Everything works fine but x-axis name is cropped from the image.I gave canvas width and height same as SVG width and height.

```
canvas.width = image.width;
canvas.height = image.height;
```

Any help appreciated.

Here is the fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/chetan530/rcwyr57w/

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just add a little padding?

```
padding: {
  bottom: 20
}
```

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3xq1rtns/

Comment: I can't edit the chart on UI. If I add padding like you suggested, it will change the way it is displaying on UI. I can do edits to downloading image. i.e. once after accessing SVG content with `getElementsByTagName("svg")`.